# passing in Geography Type and SQL converts to Geography type?

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial

I'm figuring out how to take Geography data (Lat/Lon) and add it to a SQL database using a Geography column.  I'm referencing `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` to get the `SqlGeographyBuilder`

***I should also add that this is on SQL2008r2***

***My C# project is also using .Net 4.0***

This is just a snippet of code that I'm using in my C# code to do this:

```
SqlParameter param21 = new SqlParameter();

param21.ParameterName = "@Shape";
param21.UdtTypeName = "Geography";
param21.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt;
param21.Size = 1;

SqlGeographyBuilder sqlGeogBuild = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
SqlGeography sqlGeog = null;

sqlGeogBuild.SetSrid(4267);

if (inputReader[parmLatColumnName].ToString().Length > 0 && inputReader[parmLonColumnName].ToString().Length > 0)
{
    sqlGeogBuild.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Point);
    sqlGeogBuild.BeginFigure(float.Parse(inputReader[parmLatColumnName].ToString()), float.Parse(inputReader[parmLonColumnName].ToString()));
    sqlGeogBuild.EndFigure();
    sqlGeogBuild.EndGeography();
    sqlGeog = sqlGeogBuild.ConstructedGeography;
    param21.Value = sqlGeog;
}
else
{
    param21.Value = DBNull.Value;
}

sqlComm.Parameters.Add(param21);
```

When I used the profiler I found that my query looked like this:

```
declare @p21 sys.geography
set @p21=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010C00000080B0374040000000806BD057C0)

exec insPoints @stCty=N'31256',@InstrumentType=N'''ogVal''',@FileDate='2008-01-03 00:00:00',@EntryNumber=N'''500''',@Vol=N'NULL',@Page=N'NULL',@Lessor=N'''name''',@Lessee=N'''company name''',@InstrumentDate='2000-01-12 00:00:00',@Term=3,@TermType=N'''Years''',@Expiration='2010-07-12 00:00:00',@Royalty=0.000100000,@GrossAcres=1.000000000,@AgencyId=N'NULL',@Agency=N'''Fee''',@EffDate=NULL,@Survey=N'''A500,A06,A700,A400,A900''',@Longitude=-91.000000000,@Latitude=30.000000000,@Shape=@p21
```

Why does it convert it to a Geography type when I'm passing it in as a Geography type?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server allows to define your own data types. This is called User Defined Data type (UDT).

You are using a User Defined Type to define `@Shape`. As you do not have a separate user defined data type `Georgaphy` defined in your database, it converts value to system datatype `geography`. Case is not important, it is importtant that

Using a different property of `SqlPArameter` class - `DbType` instead to reference db data type directly would have solved this. However, there is no `geography` member in [SqlDbType enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

It looks like a gap between .Net and SQL server. Try setting `DbType = "geography"`, but it is unlikely to work.

Comment: I didn't see any difference.  I do agree that it appears to be a gap between .Net and SQL but I'm wondering when the gap will disappear?

Comment: When MS adds `geography` to `SqlDbType` enum.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please have a look at this documentation page @MSDN
[Manipulating UDT Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms131086.aspx)

So from c# your query will contain a UDT data which first need to be converted into that UDT type by SQL(the default behaviour). Then it will be processed as a native type.
A agree with @Stoleg that this conversion will not appear on your profiler when there is a value defined in enum SqlDbType.

But Today we have .NET 4.6 released but yet this is not added in that enum.